# Every time I run my script it returns `_curses.error: must call setupterm() first` why?

Tags: python, linux, curses, pwntools

I'm currently trying to learn `pwn` in python. I wrote a simple Hello world script:

```
from pwn import *  

io = process('sh') 
io.sendline('echo Hello, world') 
io.recvline()
```

and let it run. Immediately two errors returned stating:

```
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database
_curses.error: must call (at least) setupterm() first
```

I've looked around and found that the solution ought to be stating:

```
export TERM=linux
export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
```

Now, export doesn't seem to be a valid command and placing a forward-slash after an equals sign returns the error `'expression expected'`.
I'm using pycharm on ubuntu 20.04.

My question then is where do I put the export code?

Comment: Please provide all information required to reproduce the problem: environment, full error output, code…

Comment: sure,
I'm using pycharm on ubuntu 20.04. 

The errors are ```Warning: _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database``` and ```_curses.error: must call (at least) setupterm() first``` as well as a long traceback (would you like that too?).

The code itself is very simple:

```from pwn import *

io = process('sh')
io.sendline('echo Hello, world')
io.recvline()```

Anything more you'd like?

Comment: Add all information to the question itself by editing it.

Comment: There you go. Again, anything else you'd like?

Comment: Try to start the program from the terminal instead of running it in Pycharm.

Comment: running the script from terminal returns ```[+] Starting local process '/usr/bin/sh': pid 103526```

Comment: Yep, it seems to be working now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run pwntools scripts in non-pty IDEs, the best way is to disable pwntools terminal interaction. This can be done by setting `PWNLIB_NOTREM` to `1` in the environment. Example from inside the script:

```py
import os
os.environ['PWNLIB_NOTERM'] = '1'

from pwn import *  # the modifications need to happen before this import

# code follows
```

The same way you can set up other environment variables, like the `TERM` you mentioned. `export TERM=linux` is a POSIX shell syntax (or bash syntax), while the python syntax for setting an environment variable like this would be:

```py
os.environ['TERM'] = 'linux'
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me in sage script.